# memory increase in centOS and Virtualbox

Tags: linux, memory, centos, virtualbox

I am using CentOS in Virtualbox.

My testing Web is frequently down, So I think reason is low memory and want to upgrade it.

origin memory is 1024MB, and in system configuration, updraded to 2048MB.

[image]

and to sync with CentOS, what commands need??

I think only upgrading memory in virtual box useless.

Must command some code in cent or chance some file.

but I did not know how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that should work.what makes you think it's not?

If you run
       cat /proc/meminfo
 before and after does it reflect the value you set?

You could also add a swap file if you haven't already